# Lua: Workaround for boolean conversion of a class variable when enclosed in parentheses

Tags: lua, parentheses

In the below code, can anyone explain why does t1:print() works but (t1):print fails. I am attempting to make something like (t1 * 3):print() work without using an intermediate variable.

```
function classTestTable(members)
  members = members or {}
  local mt = {
    __metatable = members;
    __index     = members;
  }

  function mt.print(self)
    print("something")
  end
  return mt
end

TestTable = {}
TestTable_mt = ClassTestTable(TestTable)

function TestTable:new()
   return setmetatable({targ1 = 1}, TestTable_mt )
end

TestTable t1 = TestTable:new()

t1:print() -- works fine. 
(t1):print()  -- fails with error "attempt to call a boolean value"
```

Comment: Prepend `(t1):print()` with `;`

Comment: It works.. Thanks!

Comment: your error doesn't match your code. you're calling a nil value, not a boolean value. also your code causes several errors. you don't even get near the point where you can call t1:print()

Comment: Since i couldnt copy paste production code here, i tried to mockup. But you got my logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lua expressions can extend over multiple lines.

```
print




(3)
```

Will print 3

So

```
t1:print()
(t1):print()
```

actually is equivalent to

```
t1:print()(t1):print()
```

or

```
local a = t1:print()
local b = a(t1)
b:print()
```

So you're calling the return value of `t1:print()`

To avoid that follow Egors advice and separate both statements with a semicolon.

```
t1:print();(t1):print()
```

Comment: This is a very clear explanation. It sounds like we should add semicolon as a statement separator as a good practice even if not required.

Comment: @sgowd I would not add semicolons to every line just because you might need them in 0.01% of all lines. I'd rather understand when you need them if I were you.